# Does Google Colab use my internet traffic while downloading a dataset or importing a new package into colab notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, python-module

For example when importing CIFAR-10 from Keras (using 
`from keras.datasets import cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()`)
 or temporarily installing a package like HAZM (Persian form of NLTK) using `!pip install hazm` which is not pre-installed on Google Colab, the cell containing the import statement starts to download the material it needs. I want to know if my internet traffic is used in the downloading process, or it happens on Google cloud servers and my internet connection is used only to run the code?
Thanks.

Comment: It is downloaded into your temporary,private space on Colab. Hence your internet traffic is not used.

Comment: @Prabindh Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It happens on Google cloud servers and your internet connection is used only to run the code.
I tried downloading some huge dataset using wget and my internet data wasnt affected by it.